# Not using grid anywhere in class still gives error 'cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid' in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class QuadEQPlot:

width=0;height=0;centerh=0;centerw=0;root=None

def __init__(self):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Quadratic Equation Plot")
    width = 1200
    height = 800
    centerh = height/2
    centerw=width/2

def init_widgets(self,a,b,c):
    canvas_frame = Canvas(QuadEQPlot.root,width=QuadEQPlot.width, height=QuadEQPlot.height, bg='white')

    self.plot_axis(QuadEQPlot.root,QuadEQPlot.width,QuadEQPlot.height,QuadEQPlot.centerh,QuadEQPlot.centerw,canvas_frame)

    #start point
    x=-5.00
    xy = [] #array of points

    while (x<6):
        # x coordinates
        xy.append(x*9 + QuadEQPlot.centerw)
        # y coordinates
        xy.append(QuadEQPlot.centerh - (a*(x**2) +b*x +c)*9 )
        x+=0.01


    #plot all accumulated points
    quad_line = canvas_frame.create_line(QuadEQPlot.root,xy, fill='blue')
    canvas_frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def plot_axis(self,root,width,height,centerh,centerw,canvas_frame):
    # x and y axis plot
    center_line = canvas_frame.create_line(root,0, centerh, width, centerh, fill='black')
    center_line = canvas_frame.create_line(root,centerw, 0, centerw, height, fill='black')

    diffx=9
    markno=1
    # marking on x axis
    while(diffx<=centerw and markno<7):
        xrmarking=canvas_frame.create_line(root,centerw+diffx,centerh,centerw+diffx,centerh+5,fill='black')
        # marking text on rhs of x axis
        xrtext=canvas_frame.create_text(root,centerw+diffx,centerh+12,text="%d" %markno,fill='black')
        xlmarking=canvas_frame.create_line(root,centerw-diffx,centerh,centerw-diffx,centerh+5,fill='black')
        #marking  text on lhs of x axis
        xltext=canvas_frame.create_text(root,centerw-diffx,centerh+12,text="-%d" %markno,fill='black')
        markno+=1
        diffx+=9

    #zerotext=canvas_frame.create_text(centerw+5,centerh+9,text="0",fill="black")   

    diffy=0
    markno=0
    # marking on y axis
    while(diffy<=centerh):
        yrmarking=canvas_frame.create_line(root,centerw,centerh+diffy,centerw+5,centerh+diffy,fill='black')
        #yrtext=canvas_frame.create_text(centerw+12,centerh+diffy,text="%d" %markno,fill='black')
        ylmarking=canvas_frame.create_line(root,centerw,centerh-diffy,centerw+5,centerh-diffy,fill='black')
        #yltext=canvas_frame.create_text(centerw+12,centerh-diffy,text="%d" %markno,fill='black')
        #markno+=1
        diffy+=9
```

I am calling this class from another class with a tkinter frame that uses grid..however this class doesn't use it and on line `canvas_frame.pack()` it gives the error 'cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid '

code for calling function:

```
def submit(self,a,b,c):
    obj=QuadEQPlot()
    obj.init_widgets(a,b,c)
```

code for calling class:

```
class CoefficientsDialog:

def __init__(self):
    master = Tk()
    master.minsize(width=200, height=100)
    #master.pack()
    Label(master, text="X^2     +").grid(row=2,column=5)
    Label(master, text="X         +").grid(row=4,column=5)

    e1 = Entry(master)
    e2 = Entry(master)
    e3 = Entry(master)

    a=0;b=0;c=0

    e1.grid(row=2, column=3)
    e2.grid(row=4, column=3)
    e3.grid(row=6, column=3)

    try:
        a=int(e1.get())
        b=int(e2.get())
        c=int(e3.get())

    except ValueError as e:
        a=0;b=1;c=0

    #Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
    Button(master, text='Submit', command=lambda : self.submit(a,b,c)).grid(row=8, column=3, sticky=W, pady=4)

    master.mainloop( )

def submit(self,a,b,c):
    obj=QuadEQPlot()
    obj.init_widgets(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Does that other class contain a `Tk()` call? Please consider posting a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @PM 2Ring yes it does contain one ( which uses grid) , however I have created a new root in the posted code  and all widgets specifically use it

Comment: You cannot have more than one root window in a Tkinter program. If you do that, Tkinter gets confused and weird things can happen.

Comment: I haven't had a close look at your code, but a simple solution is to create the root window outside of the classes and pass it into them as an arg of `__init__`

Comment: `QuadEQPlot.root` is not the same variable as the one you're setting to `Tk()` - it's always None, and passing that as the first parameter to a widget constructor makes it a direct child of the originally-created root window.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this structure, then it is very easy to keep on top of the different views that you have. Also, it allows you to have different root windows running at the same time:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    self.container = Frame(self)
    self.container.pack(side="top", expand=True)
    self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    for F in (pageOne, pageTwo):
        self.frame = F(self.container, self)
        self.frames[F] = self.frame
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=5)
        self.show_frame(pageOne)

    def show_frame(self, frame):
        self.frame = self.frames[frame]
        self.frame.tkraise()

class pageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="button")
        self.button1.pack()

class pageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="button")
        self.button1.pack()


app = App()
```

This shows a simple app that uses three classes, one being the root, the others being sample pages. To flip to a different Frame with the same root class, all you have to do is call `controller.show_frame(FRAMENAME)`, which will switch the frames that are on the top. To have multiple different roots, you can just make a new root class, and structure and populate it in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to comment because i got this Error and tried figuring out why, in my case it was due to using `super.init()` in my window/page classes..